# Passing project password to locked VBA project

Tags: vba, passwords

How to pass password to protected VBA project ?
To check if project number 11 is protected we can use following code:

```
Application.VBE.VBProjects(11).Protection
```

which return 1 if `yes` and 0 if `no`, but I've found no information about passing password except `SendKeys()` based method

Comment: `SendKeys` is the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/unprotecting-vba-project-t989191.html

```
'Const conPW as String = "MyPassword"
'Open VBE
Call SendKeys("%{F11}", True)
'Open Project Explorer
Call SendKeys("%(V)P", True)
'PageUp 5 times to be sure "VBAProject" is selected
Call SendKeys("{PGUP 5}", True)
'Hit Enter to give prompt, enter PW and Enter again.
Call SendKeys("{ENTER}" & conPW & "{ENTER}", True)
```

...